# Two USB cameras and ASP.NET Core

Tags: usb, camera, pi-4, web-server, webcam

I want to build a project based on the Raspberry Pi 4B and I would like to hear the opinion of someone more experienced with this platform (as I am mostly SW and did some projects with Arduinos) if it is easily feasible:

- There are two USB cameras connected to the RPI. I don't need to capture or record video from both at a single time.
- However, a live preview from both or at least one would be nice.
- What I definitely need is the ability to take static pictures from both of the cameras in parallel or with a short delay (max 1 s).
- All this stuff will be controlled (live preview, taking pictures, some image processing) by an ASP.NET Core web app (I am most experienced with this, but another language is also an option) because
- the "device" needs to be portable-just plug power, LAN, and connect with a browser.

Does the RPI 4B enough power to run such a setup?

Comment: Yes, the pi 4 is plenty powerful enough

Comment: *"the "device" needs to be portable - just plugin power"* -> Keep in mind it is not designed with the kind of energy efficiency mobile devices are, which is presumably an overall cost savings but means powering one can be quite a bit more awkward, particularly if it is for more than a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used a usb camera on the pi, nor have I used a camera from any programming launage but I would make sure you have drivers (there might be some in the latest releases of Raspberry Pi OS) and see if you can get the commandline camera program (raspistill) to work for you.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I think/hope drivers will not be an issue. Also I thought of using Motion for getting live streams from cameras. For static images I can use anything that is invokable though console and produces files.

Comment: There is also raspivid if you want.

Comment: I did not try it, but as far I read the doc it looks like raspivid supports only the camera modules, not USB cameras.